# Finding a dual basis in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Find the dual basis $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ of $\mathbb R^3$, meaning that $$\langle v_i,w_j\rangle = 
\begin{cases} 1 \mbox{ if } i=j, \\ 0 \mbox{ if } i \ne j ,\end{cases}$$
for $i,j = 1,2,3, $ where $$v_1= (1,2,0), \ \ \ \ \ v_2 = (2,3,1), \ \ \ \ \ v_3 = (-1,-1,2).$$

How would I even start a question like this?

Comment: The only place to start is to get a clear understanding of the problem statement.  What is the definition of a dual basis?  Why do you use $u$'s in the question, and then $w$'s to denote the same thing in the details section?

Why do you use ()'s to group the basis vectors, and also ()'s to group the components of an individual vector?

All these nuances suggest a lack of understanding of what the problem is asking.  The best books on the subject are by Halmos: "Finite-dimensional vector space" and "Linear algebra problem book".

Besides, unless Dylan Thomas is your real name, er....

Answer (score 0):

If $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, then the vectors
$$ w_1 = \frac{v_2 \times v_3}{v_1.(v_2 \times v_3)}, \ \ \ \ \ w_2 = \frac{v_3 \times v_1}{v_2.(v_3 \times v_1)}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ w_3 = \frac{v_1 \times v_2}{v_3.(v_1 \times v_2)}$$
obey the conditions
$$ v_i . w_j = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j \\ 0 & i \neq j\end{cases}$$
[Just calculate the dot products and you'll see!]

And $\{w_1, w_2, w_3 \}$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ because their scalar triple product is non-zero:
$$ w_1 . (w_2 \times w_3) = \frac 1 {v_1 . (v_2 \times v_3)} \neq 0.$$
[I encourage you to verify this from the identities for scalar and vector triple products - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra_relations#Addition_and_multiplication_of_vectors).]